# Character not moving in the correct direction in Scenekit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scenekit

I am making a fist person camera in Scenekit and the character is not moving relative to the rotation. Instead it is moving relative to the world axis. I want my game to be so when the player swipes forward, the character moves forward on its own x axis. Not along the x axis of the world. I tried to compensate of this with sine and cosine but it did not work. Here is my code:

```
    func lookGestureRecognized(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let velocity = gesture.velocityInView(sceneView)
    let rotationAngle = heroNode.presentationNode().rotation.w * heroNode.presentationNode().rotation.y
    var impulse = SCNVector3Make(Float(velocity.x)/50, 0, Float(velocity.y)/50)
    impulse = SCNVector3(x: impulse.x * cos(rotationAngle), y: 0, z: impulse.z * sin(rotationAngle))
    heroNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(impulse, impulse: true)
}
```

This is still making the character move in the wrong direction of the swipe. Does anyone know how to make the character move relative to its rotation?

Thanks, please ask for clarification if needed

Comment: did you get the solution for this? I also looking the right way to rotate and move the character. Considering that I've the source and destination SCNVector3 coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

the `rotation` property is made of a rotation *axis* and a rotation angle. If you want to retrieve the rotation along the *x* axis you can use the `eulerAngles` property.